# .htaccess causes 500 Error

Tags: apache2, php, oauth

I am trying to use the Rewrite Engine in Apache.
This is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLi2nks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php [QSA,R=301,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

I don't understand why this is throwing a 500 error in apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Options +FollowSymLi2nks
```

to

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: Haha. Nice catch. I would never have noticed. I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks!